# Append Option in dropdown by jquery

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have created a product attribute with select and  modify and apply ui-select on dropdown.

[image]

Now I want to append new option value in Capacity search box so How I can do this, I have added value in database from product form by ajax and get option id in return but I am not able to append value  in box.

Comment: Could you give more information? I don't understand what are you trying to do

Comment: I want to append option in capacity dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that `Capacity` in your Magento, but it does look like Category in stock Magento.

You can read about how Magento renders the Category UI in Product form here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/986f564c2617e7fb1db2cfce5116c0be8372c7e0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Categories.php#L145

You can also search for `modifyMeta and modifyMeta` in Magento code base to learn about it and apply to your project

Comment: Capacity is my custom attribute field. Let me check your solution